# How to declare a variable with subscript being numbers?

Tags: education

everyone!
I hope to declare a variable with subscript as numbers, for example, $x_{10}$, $x_{11}$, $x_{01}$ as variables. Is it possible in mathematica? If so, how to implement it so that it treats $x_{10}$ as a variable?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi ! You should add some details to your question, because it is not clear what you are actually trying to do. Add a simple (non)working example showing your goal, etc.

Comment: Although you can do something like this it is generally advised not to do this. But have a look at the [Notation package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html) if you really want this.

Comment: Is there some reason why the usual `Ctrl` + `_` won't work?

Answer (score 2):

```
Format[x[i_, j_]] :=
 Subscript[x, StringJoin[ToString /@ {i, j}]]

t = Total[{x[1, 0], x[1, 1], x[0, 1]}]
```

[image]

```
Solve[t == 1, x[0, 1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the 'Notation' package, you can create *real* symbols from (**not only!**) subscripted variables:

```
Needs["Notation`"]

makesymbol[obj_]:=With[{},      
  If[NameQ@ToString@Unevaluated@obj,Remove@obj]; (* remove possibly existing symbol first *)
  Symbolize@ParsedBoxWrapper@ToBoxes@obj;]       (* then create the new symbol *)
```

With this function, you can create a symbol like so:

```
makesymbol[Subscript[x,"01"]]
```

*Mathematica* will now treat it the same as any other (simpler) symbol.

**And the best part is:**

1. You have the same look&feel everywhere, both in your code and the generated output.
2. It works for all kinds of notation, not only `Subscript`

I hope this might be of some help to you.